# QGIS join by location not working between two shape files

Tags: qgis-plugins, vector, spatial-join, pyqgis-3, intersect

I am getting this weird error while using join attributes by location in QGIS, I have two layers - Source & Target. I am joining by target to source features using intersect option in join attributes by location.

[image]

Here is my script:

```py
QgisAll_layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
path = QgsProject.instance().absolutePath() 
joined = str(path) + "//source_target_joined.shp"
unjoined = str(path) + "//source_target_unjoined.shp"

processing.run("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", {
                'INPUT': Source,
                'JOIN': Target,
                'PREDICATE': [0], 'JOIN_FIELDS': [], 'METHOD': 0, 'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': False, 'PREFIX': 'jj',
                'OUTPUT': joined, 'NON_MATCHING': unjoined})
```

Joined attribute table not having target field values.

[image]

I understand that the spatial join of features is not happening due to some reasons, it is not able to spatially identify the features in my script.

The Join Count is coming zero, even when I have tried to reproject both the vector layers to project CRS. I have tried to add spatial index to both the points but still it did not work.

[image]

Comment: How do you add the results to QGIS after using `processing.run` in the script above? Did you try `processing.runAndLoadResults` instead of `processing.run`?

Comment: Hi @KadirŞahbaz, I think the issue now is that the join by location is not working at all even though when I reprojected both the layers into project epsg crs. The joined count is coming 0. I am not able to understand why this is not working whereas there is no error in geometry?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are using point layers, are your geometries exactly coincident for the points you expect to join? For point geometries with several decimal figures, especially after reprojecting, it may be that they do not intersect. You could try `Join by nearest` and then filter out any joins that are above an acceptable distance threshold.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem when joining attributes from my point layer to my line layer. Only some joins worked, others were left NULL. Same projection, "check validity" returned no errors and "fix geometries" didn't help. This method is a very good workaround. According to "distance", it seems my layer does consider some points to be farther away.